# A* algorithm Finite State machine?

Tags: a-star, fsm

I want to make a robot that uses path recognition to get through a maze. A great way of representing the control logic behind this robot would be to use a Finite State Machine.

Unfortunately I cannot find any examples on the internet that uses FSM to solve the A* problem. Is this because it is not possible? Are there not a finite amount of steps that you can loop through to generate a FSM for A*?

Comment: A* is a search algorithm for finding a path; FSM feels like a way to represent a path once you have it.  I don't think of FSM as a solution algorithm, but perhaps I'm ignorant and will learn something.

Comment: The humble 250,000 reputation user.

Comment: Even Jon Skeet doesn't know everything.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible in general because the Open and Closed sets are not bounded in size by a constant, so any FSM can run out of "memory". For any finite maze size it should be possible, but it's not worth it, the FSM will be gigantic: encoding not only the control flow through the algorithm but also the entire "state" of the path finding (particularly Open and Closed), you will have a ridiculous number of states for all but trivial sizes of maze. I don't even know how you could construct such an FSM for a non-trivial case.

Once you have the path, you can follow it with an FSM as control, which is a fairly "natural" thing to do I suppose. I see no advantage to encoding the path finding algorithm itself as an FSM, only huge disadvantages.